# Why organize projects inside a src folder?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

First of all, I would like to make it clear that I know that the `src` folder is not required. Indeed, one can simply create manually one directory for the project, make one valid `project.json` and one `Startup` class and everything should work fine even without Visual Studio.

My point is the following: when we create a new project using ASP.NET 5 from Visual Studio 2015 it creates a solution and inside the solution's folder it creates one `src` folder. Within this folder all projects are created.

Now why would anyone want to make one `src` folder inside the solution folder? Why not putting the projects direct onto the solution folder? Is there any advange on the organization of the project to put the projects inside a `src` folder? Why VS does that now?

Comment: Why is there a `system32` folder inside the Windows directory? Why not put all the files directly into the same directory?

Comment: It is a question of organizing the files so that it gets easier to work with them. I know that, but the source files are already inside folders, one for each project, and inside folder on those projects (like the Controllers folder). In that case, why not just let the projects folders stay direct inside the solution folder like on previous versions of VS? Why we create a new src folder to hold the projects?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/ed7564297c61fe9ab814

Comment: Thanks @tugberk, so the idea is to separate source code from test code and also to keep documentation and other things inside the solution?

Comment: It seems a convention in many other programming world. So I guess Microsoft just does the same way.

Comment: @user1620696 I created a project using a blank solution, then added a web application and class library to the solution.  In this case no "/src" folder was created.  Maybe VS assumes that if you're adding a project to a blank solution then you're intending to also add your unit tests in a separate project and thus do not need the /src or /test separation within the web application project.  However, it looks like the "global.json" also is not created using this method, so not sure of the repercussions of that.

Comment: @user1620696 more on my above comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566000/how-important-is-the-global-json-and-src-folder

Answer (score 6):

You usually have more files inside your project that are not source code related like:

- README.md
- CONTRIBUTING.md
- .gitignore
- LICENSE
- Build scripts
- Docs and tools folders, etc.

And a tons of others files that depend on your configuration. So, if you have a src folder, you don't need to mix your source code files with those.

Answer (score 4):

because you may have your code in src folder (class libraries, etc), test in your test folder, documentation in a documetation folder

in global.json you specify which folders does roslyn pick for compiling.