# Intention of src folder and global.json in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to create my project structure in ASP.NET Core but realized I'm not clear on some files and folders that ASP.NET Core is using by default. I'm starting to create a simple 3-layer project (PL, BLL, DAL). Now, how should it be properly structured? I have now something like this:

```
MySolution
    BLL (Solution Folder)
      - BL.xproj
    DAL (Solution Folder)
      - DAL.xproj
    PL (Solution Folder)
      - Solution Items
          - global.json
      - src
          - PL.xproj
```

But I am reading that everything should be in src. If that is the case, it would look something like this:

```
MySolution
    - Solution Items
        - global.json
    - src
        - BLL (Solution Folder)
          - BL.xproj
        - DAL (Solution Folder)
          - DAL.xproj
        - PL (Solution Folder)
          - PL.xproj
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why organize projects inside a src folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053381/why-organize-projects-inside-a-src-folder)

Comment: This is tricky. I just made a new DotNet core web application with the VS2017 release and there is no src folder or global.json which surprised me. I am attempting to find out why and led me here. @Set the information in your linked post is potentially only relevant to previous versions and not the current release.